# Delete duplicate lines through pattern in bash

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed, grep

I have to post-process some txt files consisted of some duplicated strings with the pattern "TER" e.g

```
ATOM  47047  H1  WAT  11303    -32.626 -35.728 -30.283  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47048  H2  WAT  11303    -33.975 -35.757 -30.969  1.00  0.00
TER
TER
TER
TER
TER
ATOM  47052  O   WAT  11305    -38.279 -35.930 -33.162  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47053  H1  WAT  11305    -37.860 -35.087 -33.334  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47054  H2  WAT  11305    -39.198 -35.793 -33.391  1.00  0.00
TER
TER
ATOM  47055  O   WAT  11306    -35.943 -38.199 -31.778  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47056  H1  WAT  11306    -35.823 -38.794 -31.039  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47057  H2  WAT  11306    -35.083 -38.162 -32.198  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM  47058  O   WAT  11307    -33.604 -37.645 -33.202  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47059  H1  WAT  11307    -34.130 -37.121 -33.805  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47060  H2  WAT  11307    -33.261 -37.012 -32.571  1.00  0.00
TER
TER
TER
ATOM  47061  O   WAT  11308    -40.428 -29.625 -32.046  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47062  H1  WAT  11308    -40.966 -28.900 -32.365  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47063  H2  WAT  11308    -40.175 -30.102 -32.837  1.00  0.00
TER
```

In this log I would like to remove all repeated more than one time a TER strings, keeping only the first string with TER. E.g

```
ATOM  47047  H1  WAT  11303    -32.626 -35.728 -30.283  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47048  H2  WAT  11303    -33.975 -35.757 -30.969  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM  47052  O   WAT  11305    -38.279 -35.930 -33.162  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47053  H1  WAT  11305    -37.860 -35.087 -33.334  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47054  H2  WAT  11305    -39.198 -35.793 -33.391  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM  47055  O   WAT  11306    -35.943 -38.199 -31.778  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47056  H1  WAT  11306    -35.823 -38.794 -31.039  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47057  H2  WAT  11306    -35.083 -38.162 -32.198  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM  47058  O   WAT  11307    -33.604 -37.645 -33.202  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47059  H1  WAT  11307    -34.130 -37.121 -33.805  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47060  H2  WAT  11307    -33.261 -37.012 -32.571  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM  47061  O   WAT  11308    -40.428 -29.625 -32.046  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47062  H1  WAT  11308    -40.966 -28.900 -32.365  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47063  H2  WAT  11308    -40.175 -30.102 -32.837  1.00  0.00
TER
```

I will be grateful for any solutions with bash commands like `sed`, `grep` or `awk`.

Answer (score 3):

Check with

```
uniq -d
```

if only the TER lines are duplicates and then

```
uniq
```

deletes the duplicated TER lines.

Answer (score 2):

Short ***sed*** solution:

```
sed '$!N;/TER\nTER/!P;D;' file
```

- `$!N` - appending each next line to the patten space (analyzing each pair of lines) till the last line `$`
- `/TER\nTER/!P;D;` - prints only the 1st line from the pattern space if they don't contain same `TER` value

The output:

```
ATOM  47047  H1  WAT  11303    -32.626 -35.728 -30.283  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47048  H2  WAT  11303    -33.975 -35.757 -30.969  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM  47052  O   WAT  11305    -38.279 -35.930 -33.162  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47053  H1  WAT  11305    -37.860 -35.087 -33.334  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47054  H2  WAT  11305    -39.198 -35.793 -33.391  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM  47055  O   WAT  11306    -35.943 -38.199 -31.778  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47056  H1  WAT  11306    -35.823 -38.794 -31.039  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47057  H2  WAT  11306    -35.083 -38.162 -32.198  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM  47058  O   WAT  11307    -33.604 -37.645 -33.202  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47059  H1  WAT  11307    -34.130 -37.121 -33.805  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47060  H2  WAT  11307    -33.261 -37.012 -32.571  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM  47061  O   WAT  11308    -40.428 -29.625 -32.046  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47062  H1  WAT  11308    -40.966 -28.900 -32.365  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47063  H2  WAT  11308    -40.175 -30.102 -32.837  1.00  0.00
TER
```

Answer (score 1):

try sed:

```
sed '/^TER/{N;/\nTER\s*$/D}' urfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the previous line and don't print the line when it's `TER`, if the previous one was also "TER":

```
awk '!/^TER$/ || prev != "TER" { print } { prev = $0 }' file
```

You can skip the explicit `{ print }` block too, since that's the default action:

```
awk '!/^TER$/ || prev != "TER"; { prev = $0 }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another awk Version:

```
awk '/^TER/{ c++; if ( c == 1 ){ print }}/^ATOM/{ print; c = 0 }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!/^TER/{c=1}c; /^TER/{c=0}' file
```

Set `c` as a flag to determine print or not.

- Under non-"TER" case, set the flag up and print.
- If met the first "TER", since `c` is still on, it would print the line, then set `c` down.
- The consecutive "TER" would not be printed since `c` kept down.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '$1=="TER" && p=="TER"{next} {print; p=$1}' file
ATOM  47047  H1  WAT  11303    -32.626 -35.728 -30.283  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47048  H2  WAT  11303    -33.975 -35.757 -30.969  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM  47052  O   WAT  11305    -38.279 -35.930 -33.162  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47053  H1  WAT  11305    -37.860 -35.087 -33.334  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47054  H2  WAT  11305    -39.198 -35.793 -33.391  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM  47055  O   WAT  11306    -35.943 -38.199 -31.778  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47056  H1  WAT  11306    -35.823 -38.794 -31.039  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47057  H2  WAT  11306    -35.083 -38.162 -32.198  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM  47058  O   WAT  11307    -33.604 -37.645 -33.202  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47059  H1  WAT  11307    -34.130 -37.121 -33.805  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47060  H2  WAT  11307    -33.261 -37.012 -32.571  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM  47061  O   WAT  11308    -40.428 -29.625 -32.046  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47062  H1  WAT  11308    -40.966 -28.900 -32.365  1.00  0.00
ATOM  47063  H2  WAT  11308    -40.175 -30.102 -32.837  1.00  0.00
TER
```